# Programmatically coping with long test suites in oUnit

Tags: ocaml, ounit

My test suite looks like this

```
let selectors =
"selectors">:::
    [
        "in_wartosc1" >:: in_wartosc1;
        "in_wartosc2" >:: in_wartosc2;
        "in_wartosc3" >:: in_wartosc3;
        "in_wartosc4" >:: in_wartosc4;
        "in_wartosc5" >:: in_wartosc5;
        "in_wartosc6" >:: in_wartosc6;
        "in_wartosc7" >:: in_wartosc7;
        "min_wartosc1" >:: min_wartosc1;
        "min_wartosc2" >:: min_wartosc2;
        "min_wartosc3" >:: min_wartosc3;
        "max_wartosc1" >:: max_wartosc1;
        "max_wartosc2" >:: max_wartosc2;
        "msr_wartosc3" >:: msr_wartosc3;
        "sr_wartosc1" >:: sr_wartosc1;
        "sr_wartosc2" >:: sr_wartosc2;
        "sr_wartosc3" >:: sr_wartosc3;
        "sr_wartosc4" >:: sr_wartosc4;
    ]
;;
```

Is there any way to reduce the crudeness of my test suite? (using some for loops, whatever)